# Регистрация на сайте (проверка логина с помощью Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, mysql

jquery ajax php mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас уже есть регистрация, но без `ajax`? Скорее всего, отправляете форму `post`-запросом. Авторизацию с использованием формы, если у вас её еще нет, сами сделать сможете.

После перехода на `ajax` для сервера почти ничего не изменится, кроме того, что в ответ будет не переадресация/вывод страницы, а отправка ответа `javascript`'у.

В `jQuery` можно использовать [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) для того, чтобы отправить `ajax`-запрос. Ответ удобно формировать в массив и отправлять в [`json`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) формате. В `PHP` для этой цели есть [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php). Есть и [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю эта ссылка поможет вам: [Ajax-валидация форм с использованием jquery](http://freehabr.ru/blog/webdev/1224.html).